# Cannot retrieve Date object from UserDefaults Swift

Tags: swift, date, userdefaults

I'd like to post and retrieve a Date object to UserDefaults.standard. As of now, I post the date object using `UserDefaults.standard.set(firstDate, forKey: "Date")` and retrieve it with `inDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Date")` where `inDate` is previously declared as a Date object.

When I do this, however, I get 
`Cannot assign value of type 'Date' to type 'Any'` and if I try to cast is `as!` a Date type the program crashes, and if I do it conditionally (`as?`), `inDate` is simply nil. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure firstDate is a Date object?

Comment: Where are you running into trouble accessing the `Date`. Is it retrieving it from `UserDefaults` or from `CoreData`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set a value for a date object in `UserDefaults`, here's how you do it:

```
let yourDate = Date() // current date
UserDefaults.standard.set(yourDate, forKey: "YourDefaultKey")
```

To retrieve it, you would use this:

```
let yourDate = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "YourDefaultKey") as! Date
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it. The problem was trying to retrieve it using standard.object instead of standard.value.

Comment: I'll add that if you're trying to get the most recent date from Core Data, storing it in `UserDefaults` might not be the best route to go. In that case, you may want to set up a `NSFetchRequest` with batch size set to 1 and fetch in descending order and use the date from the your fetched result.